# CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT gives an empty row at the bottom of a drop-down combobox

Tags: c++, winapi

Here is the screenshot for this issue. I used

`SendMessage(find, CB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT, (WPARAM)200, 0);`

to create horizontal scroll for a drop down combo box. But it gives an empty row at the bottom. How to fix this issue, please.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you code isn't adding an empty string as the first one? Can you highlight the empty line - if so, it's an actual item, and not related to the SETHORIZONTALEXTENT call.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 2 years since this question was asked, but in case anyone else bumps into this problem (like I did) here is how I solved it:

the space at the end is caused by a miscalculation on the `DropDownHeight` property, which has a default value calculated depending on the `ItemHeight` (which is dependent on the `Font`) and the `MaxDropDownItems`.

So if you added the horizontal scrollbar manually (like I did, by adding the WS_HSCROLL style) you need to recalculate the `DropDownHeight` like this:

```
DropDownHeight = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight
                 + 2 + ItemHeight * MaxDropDownItems;
```

where `2` is for the border.

**edit**

considering the system's border for wider applicability...

```
DropDownHeight = ItemHeight * MaxDropDownItems 
                 + SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight 
                 + 2 * SystemInformation.BorderSize.Height;
```

Comment: That guy is in C++ and it seems to me that this is .NET?

Comment: yes, I have C# code but I used C++ API in it to achieve this functionality, so this is possible. If he is in a C++ code he would just have to translate the code.

Comment: then again... the question is 2 years old.. so I doubt this matters to him... I answered it for whoever stumbles upon this sort of problem ion the future and the main idea is what matters, that the `dropdownheight` needs recalculation, in whichever language